# Connect Python app to Redis on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: python, docker, redis, kubernetes

A docker container with a small Python app inside it is deployed to a Kubernetes cluster that has a `redis master` and a `redis slave` service running in the cluster.  The Python app inside the Docker container is not able to connect to the `redis` across the cluster because the Python app is not configured properly to find `redis` on the network.

What specific changes need to be made to the code below in order for the Python app in `app.py` to be able to communicate successfully with the `redis` running in the same cluster?

### PYTHON APP CODE

Here is `app.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis, RedisError
import os
import socket

# Connect to Redis
redis = Redis(host="redis", db=0, socket_connect_timeout=2, socket_timeout=2)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    try:
        visits = redis.incr("counter")
    except RedisError:
        visits = "<i>cannot connect to Redis, counter disabled</i>"

    html = "<h3>Hello {name}!</h3>" \
        "<b>Hostname:</b> {hostname}<br/>" \
        "<b>Visits:</b> {visits}"
    return html.format(name=os.getenv("NAME", "world"), hostname=socket.gethostname(), visits=visits)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

---

**REDIS SERVICES IN THE SAME KUBERNETES CLUSTER**

---

The `redis master` and `redis slave` running in the cluster are from public registries and are brought into the cluster by running `kubectl apply -f` with the following JSON:

Redis Master replication controller [JSON from this link.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/v1.10.3/examples/guestbook-go/redis-master-controller.json)
Redis Master service [JSON from this link.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/v1.10.3/examples/guestbook-go/redis-master-service.json)
Redis Slave replication controller [JSON from this link.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/v1.10.3/examples/guestbook-go/redis-slave-controller.json)
Redis Slave service [JSON from this link.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/v1.10.3/examples/guestbook-go/redis-slave-service.json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What specific changes need to be made to the code below in order for the python app in app.py to be able to communicate successfully with the redis running in the same cluster?

```py
redis = Redis(host="redis-master", db=0, socket_connect_timeout=2, socket_timeout=2)
```

because the `Service` you installed is named [`redis-master`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.10.3/examples/guestbook-go/redis-master-service.json#L5), although that simple change I proposed above *assumes* that the flask app is running in the same kubernetes namespace as the `redis-master` `Service`. If that isn't true, you'll need to switch it to read:

```
redis = Redis(host="redis-master.whatever-namespace.svc.cluster.local",
```

and replace `whatever-namespace` with the actual, correct, namespace. If you don't remember or know, `kubectl get --all-namespaces=true svc | grep redis-master` will remind you.

Comment: This works, so I am marking it has the accepted answer.  Thank you.  But for the education of other readers including me, can you please elaborate on all four arguments in the `redis = Redis(host="redis-master", db=0, socket_connect_timeout=2, socket_timeout=2)` command?  I would like to understand what that is actually doing, and you only explain the host name in your current answer version.

Comment: well, not all 4 arguments, no; there is plenty of documentation for that. But the `host=` part is because kubernetes has its own DNS server, in which every `Service` is registered under its fully-qualified "cluster name", meaning the `name:` of the `Service`, and its `namespace:`, followed by `svc.cluster.local` (which one _can_ customize, but I've never seen such a thing happen). Due to the way `resolv.conf` works, as long as the DNS search path matches, you can just use the `Service` name, which is apparently what works in your case.

Answer (score 0):

if the service of redis-master is in the same namespace of flask app deployment or pod whatever use this redis-master as env variable inside the deployment file of your flask app, if not the same namespace use redis-master.whatever-namespace.svc.cluster.local
but sure while dockerizing your app use .env file